# __str__ returned non-string (type ImageFieldFile)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I am trying to print the db to see if the image saved properly when submitting the upload of an image. I get this error, **str** returned non-string (type ImageFieldFile), when printing the db. I have already looked at other problems on the platforms, they don't seem to match the fix for this problem. What am I missing for correctly submit this image to the db?
Here's the code.

```
#models.py

class Image(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='cover/pdfs', null=True, blank = True)
def __str__(self):

#forms.py
from .models import Image
from django import forms
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model= Image
    # "__all__" takes all the fields. please helps with the exception error
    fields= "__all__"
    return self.image

#views.py

def upload(request):
context = {}
userBio = Bio.objects.get(userData = User.objects.get(id = request.session['client']['id']))
if request.method == 'POST':
    dataBinder = ImageForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
    if dataBinder.is_valid():
        dataBinder.save()
        pics = Image.objects.all()
        context = {
            "imageFeed" : pics
        }
        print("RIght here.. ", pics)
    else:
        print("Not a valid input from form....")
        context = {
            "imageFeed" : "There was an error"
        }
        print("There was an error")
return render(request, "GoEnigma/dashboard.html", context)
```

This goes below my urlpatterns

```
#urls.py
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Define my root for media

```
#settings.py
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images')
```

Comment: In your Image class you start to define `def __str__(self):` but never finished, so it grabs the later `return self.image`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to get rid of def __str__self(): return self.image
From the models.